# Accessing Unique Identifier (either user, email, or phone) for Android phone in v1.5

Tags: android, account, user-accounts

Look to identify the user, email, or phone identifier from Android 1.5.  I've seen how to access account information from 2.0 and above but need this functionality in 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for hardware information try using [getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29).  I know of a few developers that use this to tag and track Android trial application installations and have been using this since at least 1.1 SDK if not before.